# fetch is told to call an http resource, but it calls an https one instead

Tags: reactjs, fetch

here's my code inside of a React app

I am using the JS native fetch

```
  fetch('http://signup.momeas.com/index.php&user=' +  email +  '&timezone=' + tz , {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        _method: 'POST',
        email: email,
        timezone: tz
      })
```

when the cal happens, the URL requested is https, not http

[image: fetch]

no matter what I do the call that goes out to the external server (at signup.momeas.com) always goes to https

Comment: Does the client send a `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header?

Comment: ummm..... I don't think so.

Comment: When I type that url in my browser it redirects me to the https version of the site.

Comment: does Fetch also redirect the request? If so, then that is my problem.

Comment: basically, when everything is on HTTPS, it works, which means it won't work locally for me when testing because locally I do not have an https connection for `127.0.0.1:3000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the docs and as far as I can tell it should work when you specify unsafe_url option

```
fetch('https://another.com/page', {
// ...
referrerPolicy: "unsafe-url" 
});
```

Try to see if that works.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Docs : https://javascript.info/fetch-api

Comment: I think the problem was the domain that I was trying to make the call to was redirecting and was also misconfigured SSL

Comment: I think the referrer-policy is called `unsafe-url` with an `-` instead of `_`

Comment: This doesn’t work if you have HSTS on the domain.