# Forcing JS fetch to use non-https

Tags: reactjs, http

I have an in-development ReactJS application that I run locally from my computer (on localhost). I have also set up local certs so that the application runs on HTTPS (https://localhost).

I also have a backend application located at an HTTP endpoint hosted in the cloud. Of course, the backend application will eventually be located at an HTTPS endpoint eventually, but that process hasn't been started yet.

I am trying to hit that HTTP endpoint from my local HTTPS ReactJS application by using `fetch`. However, something is upgrading the connection from HTTP to HTTPS automatically.

The only relevant information I have found on this is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003339/fetch-is-told-to-call-an-http-resource-but-it-calls-an-https-one-instead). I have tried the accepted answer (setting the `referrerPolicy` to `unsafe-url`) but that did not work for me.

Any other suggestions?